# Unity) How can I maintain sprites aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio

[image]

In the editor, my game works fine But in android device, all images in my game are distorted by resolution.

In some answers, use the preserve aspect in Image component, but I think sprite renderer and image cannot be used at the same time

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:unityscript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity (and I have thus removed it for you). Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the question and tags in line with each other :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images in different screen resolutions may stretch horizontally or vertically. To prevent them from doing this you can, first, add component 'Aspect Ratio Fitter' to the objects that stretch. There is 2 main modes there: Width controls height (width is always the same and height changes so that the object has the same aspect ratio) or Height controls width (height is always the same and width changed).

Besides, if your object are in Canvas you can set `UI Scale mode` to **Scale with screen size** in component *Canvas Scaler*. Then you can set the default screen resolution and it differs on a particular device, the objects in Canvas will change their sizes by themselves preserving initial appearance.